# Is there any way to trace how a network packet pass through processes?

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, network-protocols

There are some processes running on same Linux server, and they communicate each other by sockets. I wonder is there any way to trace how a packet passes through these processes?

Comment: What kind of sockets? (IP, Unix, something else,..)

Comment: Is your flavor of linux supported by [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)?  Check the bottom of that page.

Comment: @Joni tcp/udp sockets

Answer (score 0):

There can be different methods for the purpose. As all the processes are running on the same machine / server hence it means that they will be using different port address. Hence you can use wireshark to check the packets received on different ports ( and hence different processes)